# What is "userIDentityID"? in node-zendesk when call the API "verify(userID, userIDentityID, cb)"?

Tags: node.js, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am working with node-zendesk and want to verify the end-user via api, but I have no idea what is "userIDentityID" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`userIDentityID` is the ID that is automatically assigned on the creation of a user, check [this](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/user_identities#user-identities)